# Wordpress - Best Practices for Making Simple Web Services

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am creating a simple  web service using WordPress without any plugin or any third party just simple php file placed in site root that receive params and connect directly to WP database via

```
require_once('../wp-load.php');
```

and query all data from database via

```
global $wpdb, $live_site;
$data = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE user_id = '".$sessionData['userID']."' AND meta_key='last_login_time'"));
```

Now every thing is going well but including wp-load.php file will load all wp site with all installed plugins and lots of php files included that really not needed.

I need a way to enhance that "Web Services" by implement **YAGNI** [(You aren't gonna need it)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)

Basically How to include  **global $wpdb, $live_site;** and all wp functions without load any other unnecessary files?

Comment: why is there "wordpress" and "best practices" in same sentence ?

Comment: Why is "best practices" written in a [tag:wordpress] question?

Comment: Have you considered [BackPress](http://backpress.org/) which provides the WordPress core functionality for web applications?

Comment: @tereško I cant get what is your points ... I need the best practices for making API in Wp? Is that wrong? if u have any edit for my question feel free to suggest it to enhance that question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All above answers is very helpful but in my case not fit because I need a way to load data from database without load all wp plugins, themes and setting actually without

```
require_once('../wp-load.php');
```

or

```
require_once('../wp-config.php');
```

or

require_once('../wp-setting.php');

simply I have a folder in root site contains [Redbeanphp](http://redbeanphp.com/) lib and config.php file and my php files looks like:

```
require_once('config.php');
require_once 'vendor/rb.php';
global $live_site;

R::setup('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
$categories = R::getAll('select * from wp_term_taxonomy WHERE parent = 4);
```

I hope that help any one really It's pretty simple :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you check out the [WordPress REST API](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API) which is [proposed for Core inclusion in WordPress 3.9](http://make.wordpress.org/core/version-3-9-project-schedule/). This way you don't need to hack your own stuff but will get a well tested API that is maintained by the WordPress devs.
From what you read the guys over at wordpress.com would like to migrate their own API to the core and they will make sure no terrible performance issues hit their servers.

Answer (score 1):

[This talk](https://gist.github.com/jasonrhodes/9570529) has a lot of useful information about modern development in WordPress, but the most pertinent topic would be [this plugin](https://github.com/johnshopkins/wp-simple-json-api) which generates a read-only JSON API.